# Why does query performance diminish with additional join conditions

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I have a simple query with two tables. `massfehler_hardware` has 50K rows and *no indexes*. `f_produkt` has 38M rows with a *clustered unique index* on account_number, item_number, contract_number, [and some other columns]

Following query takes 11 seconds:

```
select count(distinct a.serial_number)
from massfehler_hardware a
join f_produkt f
on a.account_number = f.account_number
where f.product_code = 'VOD'
```

With two additional join conditions, it gets 5x slower:

```
select count(distinct a.serial_number)
from massfehler_hardware a
join f_produkt f
on a.account_number = f.account_number
and a.service_address_id = f.service_address_id
and a.outlet_location = f.outlet_code
where f.product_code = 'VOD'
```

Why is the impact of additional join conditions so extreme? Joining with only account_number already limits the number of results to approx 46K, so the additional join conditions (service_address_id and outlet_location) should only run on those 46K rows, and shouldn't increase the costs so much. What do I miss?

Strangely enough, when I compare the execution plans, the estimated relative cost of the faster running query is bigger! (57%)

Here are the two execution plans respectively:

Faster running query:
[image: Faster running query]

Slower running query:
[image: Slower running query]

Comment: Ca you post the `create table`/`alter table` statements aswell? It likely has to do with the conditions referencing non-indexed columns.

Comment: Fields that you need from the 2nd table are such that there's no need to read the base table, but when you add more fields then index scan can't be used?

Comment: The estimated plans can help but to really get down to the root of performance issues you need to look at the actual execution plans.

Comment: I cannot give much detail about the table structure for security reasons but  there is only one index, which covers following columns of f_produkt:  `account_number, item_number, contract_number, product_code, product_seq, region, building_id, regkz` (in this given order)

Comment: But even though the two additional join columns are not included in the index, I would expect from the SQL Server that it joins with account_number only first, which is the main index column, and then further limit the result set by applying the two additional on this intermediate result set. Why does it not do that??

Comment: That isn't how joins work. They don't start filtering rows for each of the conditions and then filter again for the next join etc. Each join is evaluated on the entire list of predicates. That means if you are joining on two columns that are not indexed you are not going to be able to utilize your index because the index is not a covering index. That means it will be forced to look at each and every row to determine if it should be included in the results.

Comment: @SeanLange, I don't agree - the fact that the index is not covering does not mean it is not utilized - the order of the list of index columns vs. the columns  used in the join condition important to say that.

Comment: @DimitarKyuchukov true. It would still be utilized but as a scan instead of seek. Perhaps saying not useful would have been better.

Comment: @ercan , the actual execution plan will say more - and for sure the exact index creation statements so that we know what indices are we discussing.

Comment: @SeanLange if the index is on A and B and you join on A, B and C it will not be a scan - it will usually be a seek with a key lookup for C and filter operation after that. Yes, you will say key lookup is slow, but still usually much faster than scan especially if the A and B combination has favorable cardinality. And having said that without actual execution plans we are only speculating.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that your query is forcing the DB to do more work. It has to apply two new filters, and even if it chooses the optimal execution, an un-indexed varchar comparison can be slow.  In terms of optimizing your query though, you should be making use of `EXISTS` instead of a `JOIN`.  With a `JOIN`, the DB has to process every row, but since you just want the distinct count, an `EXISTS` statement should generally be faster.  Look at what the explain plan for this query looks like.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.serial_number)
FROM massfehler_hardware a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM f_produkt f 
             WHERE a.account_number = f.account_number AND
                   a.service_address_id = f.service_address_id AND
                   a.outlet_location = f.outlet_code AND
                   f.product_code = 'VOD')
```